# Using output of aws cli as input for ssh-keygen (-yf)

Tags: amazon-web-services, output, ssh-keygen

I have the following challenge.
A private ssh-key is stored in aws secretmanager as secret.
Now I want to get this secret with cli and use it directly in ssh-keygen to get the corresponding public key

ssh-keygen can do that with -y parameter, but has to get a file as input.

Now the problem is, that the output is not usable when I pipe it to a file OR stdin

Examples:

Doesn´t work:

```
ssh-keygen -yf /dev/stdin <<<$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <secretname> --region <secret>  --output text --query SecretString)
```

Nor this:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <secretname> --region <secret>  --output text --query SecretString > tempfile.key
chmod 600 tempfile.key
ssh-keygen -yf tempfile.key
```

Both commands result in an interactive "Enter passphrase" (the key has no passphrase, so it seems to be that the contents are messed)

When I copy / paste the output manually to file and use the file it works.

So, what´s my problem here ?

Many thanks in advance and Greetings,

JP

UPDATE:

vimdiff shows me a difference in whitespace, but I have no clue how to solve this :-(

[image]

Comment: Have you compared the contents of `tempfile.key` to what you copy-pasted? My guess -- and it's just a guess -- is that embedded newlines are being rendered as `\n` by the CLI.

Comment: updated the main post .... yeah, there is a difference in whitespace .... :-(